# Stirling numbers of first kind induction proof

Tags: combinatorics

Prove by induction that $s(n, n-1) =$ $-$$n \choose 2$, where $s(n,k)$ is a Stirling number of the first kind.

Workings:

Proof:

Base Case: $n = 2$

$s(2,1) = -1$

$-$ ${n} \choose {2}$ $= -1$

$-1 = -1$

Base case holds.

Induction hypothesis:

Suppose that $s(n,n-1) = -\binom{n}{2}$ holds for some $n$.

Then for $n+1$:

$s(n+1,n) = $

Now I'm not sure on what to do any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use the recurrence formula 
$$ s(n+1,k) = -ns(n,k) + s(n,k-1) $$
for the Stirling numbers.
We have
\begin{align*}
  s(n+1,n) &= -ns(n,n) + s(n,n-1)\\
           &= -n - \binom n2\\
           &= -\binom{n+1}2
\end{align*}

Comment: I see thanks for the help.